# Difference of two Dataframes is not exact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to get random values of dataframe DF1 and them storing them in a new variable DF2. I want to take difference to the remaining values will be not in origional dataframe DF1. I need to do this task without using sklearn library.
I tried two ways to get random values and they are following:
Method 1:

```
DF2 = DF1.sample(n = 1000, random_state = 10)
```

Method 2:

```
chosen_idx = np.random.choice(2000, replace = False, size = 1000)
DF2 = DF1.iloc[chosen_idx]
```

Following is how I take their difference to get dataframe with remaining values, say DF3:

```
DF3 = pd.concat([DF1, DF2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

The problem is, the difference of `len(DF1)`, `len(DF2)` and `len(DF3)` should be 0. But it is not. I am not sure where I am wrong. Following is my actual code with different variables:

```
def train_validation_test(set_dataframe):
  if isinstance(set_dataframe, pd.DataFrame):
    df_length = len(set_dataframe.index)
    seventy = math.floor(df_length*0.7)
    seventy = seventy if seventy%2==0 else seventy+1
    remaining = int((df_length - seventy)/2)
    # one = set_dataframe.sample(n = seventy, random_state = 10)
    chosen_idx = np.random.choice(df_length, replace = False, size = seventy)
    one = set_dataframe.iloc[chosen_idx]
    return one
  
  else:
    return print('Argument passed is not dataframe. Please pass dataframe as argument.')
abc = train_validation_test(task01_df)


xyz = pd.concat([task01_df, abc]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)


print(len(task01_df) - len(abc) - len(xyz))
```

The result is `7` but it is depending on `random_state`. It is never `0` and having varying value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from `sklearn`:

```
# Python env: pip install sklearn
# Conda env: conda install sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


DF1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (2000, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

DF2, DF3 = train_test_split(DF1, train_size=1000)
```

Output:

```
>>> DF1.shape
(2000, 3)

>>> DF2.shape
(1000, 3)

>>> DF3.shape
(1000, 3)

>>> DF2.index.intersection(DF3.index)
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')  # no overlaps
```

Comment: I cant use sklearn library or train_test_split() as part of this. Hence I am trying to do this manually. My solution would work only if I can find perfect difference of two datasets

Comment: You want to split your dataframe into 70/30?

Comment: Yes. 70 one side and two of 15 each. So I'll repeat this process